# Updating the label from changing the value from rating

Tags: vb.net

How do I code peer to peer textboxes connected to a label?

It is a rating system in asp.net using VB.net code. When I rate "1" to `textbox1`, the `textbox2` will appear in the `label1`. Then when I rate 2 in `textbox1`, the `textbox2` value will appear in `label2`. The same in `textbox3` when I rate "1", `textbox4` will appear to `label 1'.

The problem is... when I changed the value of `textbox1` from "1" to "3", the value of label is not clearing, but it goes to `label3`

How can I possibly update the recent label from changing the value of rate!

Comment: ask me if you did not understand my question.. thank you..

Comment: Did you write any code for this? Is it not working? How is it not working? Any error? What unexpected behavior you are seeing?

Comment: yes i have a code sir...

Comment: it is working... but my code is conflicting to each other...

Comment: This is the code for the textbox1 named "tb_rate1" which you can rate 1 to 50: If Val(tb_rate1.Text) = 1 Then
            lbl_r1.Text = tb_name1.Text
        ElseIf Val(tb_rate1.Text) = 2 Then
            lbl_r2.Text = tb_name1.Text

Comment: the problem is... when i change the value of tb_rate1 (ex. from "1" to "2") then the value of tb_name1 beside the tb_rate1 will appear in the label named "lbl_r2"... so, the "lbl_r1" must erase the current value from tb_name1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click on all of your textboxes and in their **properties**, set **autopost** back to **true**

also i suggest you to use radio buttons for rating rather than `textbox`. * much easier to manage

Comment: Ok, i wll try that sir

Comment: its not applicable because the rating in textbox1 is a number ranging from 1 to 50